# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a procedure and got this message

***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.***

```
create procedure consultarEquipo (@id varchar(10), @marca varchar(20),
@year int, @factura varchar(50), @poliza varchar(30))
as begin

select * from C_EQUIPOS
where (ID_EQUIPO like '%'+@id+'%' and
MARCA like '%'+@marca+'%' and
YEAR like '%'+@year+'%' and
FACTURA like '%'+@factura+'%' and
SEGURO like '%'+@poliza+'%')

end
go
```

I don't know what it might be, but when I change the procedure to just this:

```
create procedure consultarEquipo (@id varchar(10), @marca varchar(20))
as begin

select * from C_EQUIPOS
where (ID_EQUIPO like '%'+@id+'%' and
MARCA like '%'+@marca+'%')

end
go
```

It seems to work just fine. I'm a newbie on SQL so any help would be appreciated, maybe there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `Year` is presumably an `int` column, so you shouldn't try to do a string comparison directly. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `YEAR like '%'+@year+'%'`, I'd say either the year is equal or it is not, it shouldn't be partially equal to the variable. Further, please Tag your question with the appropriate dbms, you probably aren't using both sql server and mysql. Finally, for more complete answers post your schema and sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the `where` clause:

```
YEAR like '%'+@year+'%' and
```

`@year` is an integer.  So, you need to convert it to a string:

```
YEAR like '%'+ cast(@year as varchar(255)) + '%' and
```

Why you are using `like` for a column called `YEAR` is suspicious.  Perhaps you just want:

```
(YEAR = @year or @year IS NULL) and
```